# Do we need to destroy semaphores?

Tags: c++, free, destructor, semaphore

I have a class working with (non-static) semaphores.

In the destructor of this class I'm freeing dynamically allocated memory.

The class' objects are not supposed to be "destructed" while we still `wait` for a semaphore.

Do I still need to use `sem_destroy` in the class' destructor to make sure the semaphores are terminated?

Comment: Of course.  Having the destructor called while the semaphores are in use is a bug.

Comment: I'm using `semaphore.h` with linux `g++`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In C++ the dynamically added objects aren't destroyed automatically and you should destroy any object you have created with a pointer like this:

```
semaphore *S =  ...
```

Comment: I'm not talking about destroying dynamically added objects.. I'm talking specifically about destroying semaphores

Answer (score 0):

If you do not call sem_destroy for a semaphore, then it is implicitly destroyed when the memory in which semaphore resides is deallocated. If your semaphore is in non-shared memory them semaphore is destroyed implicitly when the process calls exit or exec. If the semaphore is in the shared memory then it is destroyed, after the last process has closed.

Comment: Can you point to where in the standard it says that?  I can't find it.  (I suspect that it might be true in some, or maybe even all implementations, but I can't find the wording guaranteeing it in the standard.)

Comment: I read this in book a week ago by O reily, I believe it name was POSIX:Programming for the Real World

Comment: I can't find it in the Posix standard.  But then, I can't find anything which says that you have to destruct a semaphore anyway, or resources will be leaked, so I don't know.  (For `pthread_mutex_t`, Posix is quite clear: an implementation may store a pointer to system resources or heap memory in it, and failing to destroy it correctly can leak resources.  I would expect that the same thing holds for `sem_t`.)